# Delphi Passing Dynamic array of Records to function

Tags: arrays, delphi, dynamic

I have a Dynamc array of Records and I wish to pass one of the items in the array to a function by reference

So for example one of the array items -  AArray[1].arecorditem is a string of 6 characters String[6]

the function would be  -

```
function dosomething(var AStringVal:string):Integer;
```

So I would execute

```
Aresult:= dosomething(AArray[1].arecorditem);
```

however when I try to compile I get the Error Type of actual and formal var parameters must be identical.

Is this possible to do or should I assign the array item to a string and then pass the string to the function.

Thanks

Colin

Answer (score 5):

Your question title and the actual question are **not the same**, so I'll give you an overview of both subjects.

You need to define an **Array Type**

```
TMyRecord = record
  Field1: String
  Field2: String
end;

TMyRecordArray = Array of TMyRecord

function DoSomething(const ARecordArray: TMyRecordArray): Integer;
```

This is if you want to pass an *entire dynamic array of items* to the function. If you just want to pass one item, you'd define  the function like this:

```
function DoSomething(const ARecord: TMyRecord): Integer;
```

Now, if you want to pass the *value* of Field1 to the function, you would have to define the function as:

```
function DoSomething(const AField: String): Integer;
```

**You cannot define the parameter as `var`or you'll end up with the error you're getting!**

Additional:

As others have been saying, if you're using a fixed-length String for the field, you need to define it as a Type just as I have demonstrated above for `TMyRecordArray`.

```
TString6 = String[6];
```

Use that Type both for your Field, and your function Parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to create a type:

```
    type
      TName = string[80];
```

So you can call your function this way:

```
    function doSomething(var name: TName): Integer;
    begin
        ...
        ...
        ...
    end;
```

## Working Example

```
program HelloWorld;

type
  TName = string[80];

type
  TCustomer = record
    name : Name;
    age : byte;
  end;

procedure qwerty(var name: TName);
begin
  name := 'doSomething';
end;

var
  customers : array[1..3] of TCustomer;
  b : Byte;
begin

  with customers[1] do
  begin
    name := 'qwerty';
    age := 17;
  end;

  with customers[2] do
  begin
    name := 'poiuy';
    age := 18;
  end;

  writeln(customers[1].name);

  qwerty(customers[1].name);
  writeln(customers[1].name);

  Readln(b);
end.
```

Comment: Try to use the unwritten conventions in formatting and syntax. Types have the **T** on the beginning of the word just like I have in my nick ;) Now you're mixing two things together, check the syntax `Name: Name`.

Comment: @TLama Are you a class or an instance?  ;-)

Comment: @David, I'm just a type :) Sometimes like a class because I feel like I need more instances of me doing the same things on many places and sometimes like a declared boolean type, so it depends :)

Comment: @TLama I feel like a Thread, because I always need more than one of me performing the same task at the same time to achieve a quicker result!

Answer (score 1):

String[6] is a ShortString with a maximum length of 255 characters. You need to either change the definition of doSomething to something like:

```
function dosomething(var AStringVal:string[6]):Integer;
```

or

```
  function dosomething(var AStringVal:ShortString):Integer;
```

or change the definition of the record so that arecorditem is of type String (as opposed to String[6]).

Comment: string[6] is not a valid type in a function/procedure declaration. Declare it outside, Type Str6 = string[6];

Answer (score 0):

If you're not changing the value of the parameter in the function, you can change the variable type in the function declaration to `const` instead of `var`, the compiler will do the conversion for you:

Change from:

```
procedure doSomething(var AStringVal: String);
```

To this:

```
procedure doSomething(const AStringVal: String);
```

Now you can do this, without complaint:

```
var
  myShortString: String[6];
begin
  myShortString := '123456';
  doSomething(myShortString);
end;
```

When you pass variables by reference, they must be the same type. When you pass by other means, the compiler will try to convert for you.