# Returning an Array of Extended

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am trying to return an array of extended in VCL form of Delphi. The code is as follows:-

```
function Calc_Er(
  n: Integer; 
  RadioGroup3.ItemIndex : Boolean; 
  K1, K2 : Extended;
  factor1, factor2, p, hh, ten, r : Array of Real; 
  Pa: extended ) : Array of Extended;
begin
    if RadioGroup3.ItemIndex = 0 then
      begin
        if hh[n] < factor1[n] then
          begin
            Er[n] := K2 * (K1 + p[n]);
          end
        else if (hh[n] < factor2[n]) and (hh[n] > factor1[n]) then
          begin
            Er_stack := K2 * (K1 + p[n]);
            Er[n] := (h / 100 + hh[n]) / ((h / 100 / Er_stack[n]) + hh[n] * (ten[n] * h / r[n] + Pa) / Sqr(p + ten[n] * h / r[n] + Pa));
          end
        else
          begin
            Er[n] := Sqr(p[n] + Pa + ten[n] * h / r[n]) / (ten[n] * h / r + Pa);
          end;
      end
    else
      begin
        Er[n] := K2 * (K1 + p[n]);
      end;
end;
```

It shows an error with the RadioGroup3 as 'Undeclared Identifier' or 'Missing Parameter type' though I have used it in the entire code. I am not able to understand the error. Please have a look!

Comment: `RadioGroup3.ItemIndex : Boolean` this is not a proper argument name

Comment: @n0rd then what should be done? as I want to use the Item Index property.

Comment: First, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403578/delphi-passing-dynamic-array-of-records-to-function Second, decide if you want to have this function to be free or class member. If you want it to be class member, you'd have access to all other class members of the same instance implicitly and don't have to pass them inside function; if you don't want it to be class member, simply pass it as a regular integer argument (something like 'ItemIndex:Integer'). Why is it even `Boolean` in your case?

Comment: @Jack: Like n0rd told you, `Calc_Er()` is not declared as a member of your Form class that owns the `RadioGroup3` object, that is why you get the error. So either make `Calc_Er()` a member of the Form class, or else you will have to use the Form's global pointer to reach its members, or else pass the desired `ItemIndex` as an input parameter to `Calc_Er()`. And if you don't know how to do any of these things, then you need to stop what you are doing and go re-learn Delphi fundamentals.

Comment: 1) RadioGroup.ItemIndex is not a Boolean; it's an Integer. 2) Your function is not a member of the form, so it has no access to `RadioGroup3`, either as a parameter name or within the function code. 3) If you don't show how you tried to declare it, we can't tell you why it didn't work. You need to provide the specific code that "didn't work" if you want us to help you find out why it didn't.

Comment: You probably want to use double rather than extended.

Comment: @David yeah that would be more faster!
btw I took out the ItemIndex from the variable part as it's a property of RadioGroup and I tried to call the function as **k := Calc_Er(1; K1, K2, Pa; hh[1], r[1], p[1], factor1[1], factor2[1], ten[1]; RadioGroup3);** it shows an error 'Not enough actual parameters'. Any comments?

Comment: Clearly you aren't passing enough parameters. 100% you should not be passing a radio group. Pass a boolean as everyone else says. What is the function doing? Catenary? Is `ten` tension?

Comment: @David yeah ten is tension and the output is an array of Elastic Radial Modulus for different values of radius. I tried not to pass the RadioGroup but I am getting errors, so could you please write down the declaration part?

Comment: You know how to declare a parameter. You know how to specify the type. You already know how to do this. I advise you to slow down and think more about the problem. We can help if you let us.

Comment: @David yeah I know how to declare a parameter but I can't just write *RadioGroup3 : Boolean; ItemIndex : Integer* because I can't pass a value to ItemIndex as it should be done automatically when the user tries to click any RadioButton of the RadioGroup in the Design.

Comment: First of all, please can you come up with a good name for the boolean. When item 0 of the radio group is selected, one branch is chose, otherwise a different branch is chosen. I cannot help you until we get some names and terminology that describe what is going on.

Comment: @David the RadioGroup3 is 'Air Entrainment' when ItemIndex = 0 is chosen then the code allows air calculations otherwise doesn't allow it.

Comment: Good. Then you should declare the parameter as follows `AccountForAirEntrainment: Boolean` and then the `if` statement in the body of the function should read `if AccountForAirEntrainment then`. When you call the function you might write `AccountForAirEntrainment := CalculationModeRadioGroup.ItemIndex = 0; Er := CalcEr(..., AccountForAirEntrainment, ...);`. This makes the code much more readable. Please give everything names. You cannot hope to write a program with entities that are not named. Please, `RadioGroup3` is just appalling.

Comment: @David I tried to run it and there are no errors but I wanted to check the value of Er[1] as you suggested *  AllowAirCalculation := RadioGroup3.ItemIndex = 0;
  Er := Calc_Er();
  k := Er[1];* and then stored the value of k in a TEdit but I got an unexpected error in the last else statement of the function "Access violation at address 005E555C in module Project2.exe. Read of address 02059870." I mean since I have selected the ItemIndex = 0 then why is it going to the last else statement and even if it does then why not show an error in the first if statement *Er[n] := K2 * (K1 + p[n])*?

Comment: I cannot debug code that I cannot see. We are four steps removed from the original question. You already accepted an answer here. You need to step back a little, slow down, and try to learn. For a start, learn to use your debugger.

Comment: @David also when I tried to put n=1 in Calc_Er() it showed a message "no expected parameters" comments?

Comment: I cannot comment on that which I cannot see. I suggest you follow the advice I have already given you.

Comment: @okay I'll try to go through it again till I find the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, I've learned that you never want to use the construct "array of ..." in either parameter lists or return types on functions.

Declare something like this first:

```
type
  TExtArray = array of extended;
  TRealArray = array of real;
```

Then use these instead of "array of extended" and "array of real".

You'll also need to call SetLength on the dynamic arrays, including Result.

As others have mentioned, "RadioGroup3.ItemIndex" cannot be used as a parameter in a function, regardless if it's correctly typed or not. Just pass in an integer value.

Comment: it works pretty fine but if try to declare the function as ***function Calc_Er(n: Integer; RadioGroup3: TRadioGroup; ItemIndex : Integer; K1, K2 : Extended; factor1, factor2, p, hh, ten, r : TRealArray; Pa: extended ) : TExtArray ;*** then it throws error 'Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TForm1.Calc_Er'
.....Any reason?

Comment: @Jack - Read the error, it says, it should be "function TForm1.Calc_Er", not "function Calc_Er".

Comment: BTW, why do you insist on passing in the TRadioGroup object when all you're interested in is if the ItemIndex value is zero or not? Just use a boolean argument and pass in the value "(RadioGroup3.ItemIndex = 0)". It'll evaluate as a boolean.

Comment: @David if we pass the Boolean in the function then it shows an error 'Missing Parameter type' or Undeclared Identifier RadioGroup. Maybe I am not getting what you are saying.

Comment: @Jack - It's definitely possible to declare a boolean parameter in a function and then to pass a boolean to it.

Comment: This advice is not great. Open array parameters are to be encouraged. They make functions more general. They can be called with a wider and more flexible set of parameters. It's important also to stress that copying parameters, as per the code in the question leads to poor perf. Use `const` or perhaps `var`.

Comment: @Jack The function does not need to access or even know about the TRadioGroup. You only refer to it once where you say: "if RadioGroup3.ItemIndex = 0 then". It's simply being used as a boolean flag. So on your function, have an argument like "aFlag : boolean" and replace that line with, "if aFlag then". Where you call the function, just say, "(RadioGroup3.ItemIndex = 0)" to pass in a boolean value as the value of that flag.

Answer (score 2):

David's answer is basically correct, but I should just point out that, if this is Delphi XE, you should declare it as `TArray<extended>`.  That can save various compatibility issues down the road.

Comment: Because the OP had a couple of glaring errors in his example, that's all anybody picked up on before I posted my answer. Nobody noticed the more subtle problem with typing, which was really the issue here. So that's what I focused on. However, if you're working with a version of Delphi that supports generics, that's probably a better way to go, for sure.